# Adding cristality to ride and hats

Tags: frequency, ride-cymbal

Most rides and hats are quite bright yet not so crystal as I would like, the question is: what frequencies must I touch to make them crystal. I mean like triangles for instance.

This is the sound of the ride that I want to have:

Comment: Are you asking how to EQ the cymbals in a recording situation?

Comment: EQ can't add what's not there. If it's there, it can make it a bit louder, but a better way to look at that is even boosting EQ is really just making the other frequencies quieter. The best way to get the cymbal sounds you like is to get cymbals that have that sound.

Comment: @ToddWilcox What if I dont have those cymbols?

Comment: If you can't be with the one you love, love the one you're with. Figure out what's good about the cymbals you have and emphasize that.

Comment: You can't use EQ to turn one cymbal into another cymbal. It's just not possible. So you can be snarky all you want, it's not going to help you in your situation.

Comment: I think we need you to define "crystal." To me, especially when juxtaposed against "bright" means "sparkling" which means to me, broken or distorted. As a side note: some people think helium or sulfur hexaflouride alter the pitch of your voice, but it really behaves as a frequency-cut filter. Try an aggressive low cut filter, and then just enough gain to clip, and then use a "wah" or similar to sweep through until you find it.

Comment: @Yorik By crystal, i mean a sound like a triangle gives, a very high dzing!

Comment: What if you play a triangle track along with the high hat and mix them together? That could sound pretty cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally use EQ to boost the frequency ranges that I want and drop the volume on the hi-hat channel to suit.

The key frequencies I use for tweaking hi-hats are:

**200 to 300 Hz** - This is where the metallic "chink" sound usually is.

**6,000 Hz +** - This is where hissy "tsss" sound usually is.

To get a more metallic sound, enhance with a mid to narrow band at 200-300 Hz. To get more 'sizzle', enhance with a high-shelf from around 6,000 Hz.

You should use these as approximations and adjust to suit your particular tastes but I hope it serves as a starting point at least.

To make it 'ring' more you'll need to play about with ring modulators and reverbs.